# Angular Js - Manipulate DOM and add click behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, click, dom-manipulation

I am using a leaflet map with angular and added a legend. To change the appearance of the map I manipulated the DOM after the view has loaded with a $timeout-method. The legend should be clickable to select which items should appear on the map. So I tried to make an alert, when one item in the legend is clicked. For that I changed the item to a button just to be sure. But the button click doesn't work because it doesn't know the method.

Does anybody know how to call a ng-click method on a manipulated DOM object?

Here is some of my code:

controller.js

```
//initiating of the map happend before 
//now loading of the markers and manipulating of the map
function activate() {
    projectService.getMarkers(vm, 'projectsData');
    bindEventListener();

    $timeout( function() {
        getLegendElement();
    });
}

//manipulating of the legend element to make a button with a ng-click
function getLegendElement() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("legend leaflet-control");
    element[0].children[0].innerHTML = '<button ng-click="showAlert()">ok</button>';
}

//showing the alert
$scope.showAlert = function(){
    $window.alert("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DOM manipulation SHOULD be moved to a directive.  However, if you wanted to keep it in your controller, you need to inject `$compile` into your controller and invoke it on your dynamically generated html.

```
function getLegendElement() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("legend leaflet-control");
    element[0].children[0].innerHTML = '<button ng-click="showAlert()">ok</button>';
    $compile(element)($scope);
}
```

The reason for this is because Angular looks for event bindings that it needs to generate when it first parses your template.  Since you are applying a late event that needs binding to html that did not exist when your template was originally parsed, you need to tell Angular to update its understanding of the template.  The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) calls this out:

> **$compile**
>
> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and
> the template together.

Comment: thank you! that worked! I will think about moving it all into a directive.

Comment: Glad to help!  The reason for moving it to a directive is that it cleans up your separation of DOM interaction to actual business logic.  And since it's the recommended Angular approach, it'll keep you more consistent with industry standards :).